# How do I make it so I only need my api key referenced once?

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3

I am teaching myself how to use python and django to access the google places api to make nearby searches for different types of gyms.

I was only taught how to use python and django with databases you build locally.

I wrote out a full Get request for they four different searches I am doing. I looked up examples but none seem to work for me.

```py
allgyms = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=38.9208,-77.036&radius=2500&type=gym&key=AIzaSyDOwVK7bGap6b5Mpct1cjKMp7swFGi3uGg')
all_text = allgyms.text
alljson = json.loads(all_text)

healthclubs = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=38.9208,-77.036&radius=2500&type=gym&keyword=healthclub&key=AIzaSyDOwVK7bGap6b5Mpct1cjKMp7swFGi3uGg')
health_text = healthclubs.text
healthjson = json.loads(health_text)

crossfit = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=38.9208,-77.036&radius=2500&type=gym&keyword=crossfit&key=AIzaSyDOwVK7bGap6b5Mpct1cjKMp7swFGi3uGg')
cross_text = crossfit.text
crossjson = json.loads(cross_text)
```

I really would like to be pointed in the right direction on how to have the api key referenced only one time while changing the keywords.

Comment: Define a [function](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Functions)

Comment: What's the output of print(all_text)?

Comment: cannot you use string concatenation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for better readability and better reusability

```
BASE_URL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?'
LOCATION = '38.9208,-77.036'
RADIUS = '2500'
TYPE = 'gym'
API_KEY = 'AIzaSyDOwVK7bGap6b5Mpct1cjKMp7swFGi3uGg'
KEYWORDS = ''

allgyms = requests.get(BASE_URL+'location='+LOCATION+'&radius='+RADIUS+'&type='+TYPE+'&key='+API_KEY) all_text = allgyms.text 
alljson = json.loads(all_text)

KEYWORDS = 'healthclub'
healthclubs = requests.get(BASE_URL+'location='+LOCATION+'&radius='+RADIUS+'&type='+TYPE+'&keyword='+KEYWORDS+'&key='+API_KEY) 
health_text = healthclubs.text 
healthjson = json.loads(health_text)


KEYWORDS = 'crossfit'
crossfit = requests.get(BASE_URL+'location='+LOCATION+'&radius='+RADIUS+'&type='+TYPE+'&keyword='+KEYWORDS+'&key='+API_KEY) 

cross_text = crossfit.text 
crossjson = json.loads(cross_text)
```

as V-R suggested in a comment you can go further and define function which makes things more reusable allowing you to use the that function in other places of your application

**Function implementation**

```
def makeRequest(location, radius, type, keywords):
    BASE_URL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?'
    API_KEY = 'AIzaSyDOwVK7bGap6b5Mpct1cjKMp7swFGi3uGg'
    result = requests.get(BASE_URL+'location='+location+'&radius='+radius+'&type='+type+'&keyword='+keywords+'&key='+API_KEY)
    jsonResult = json.loads(result)
    return jsonResult
```

**Function invocation**

```
json = makeRequest('38.9208,-77.036', '2500', 'gym', '')
```

Let me know if there is an issue